# Eclim setup for Java development

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

I have a question about Eclim and setting it up basically. I've gone through the installation as according to the website, but when I try to test it as the website says also, I get this error:
Unable to connect to eclimd (port:9091) - connect: Connection refused.

Can someone guide me through fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you started eclimd ?

you need to start eclimd 
im starting it as `/home/alex/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/eclimd`

and then you can use it.